# Different Teffilin, now what am I required to do?

Tags: halacha, minhag, tefilin

If I do not have my regular Teffilin one morning and need to borrow someone else's, but that person's Teffilin are different from mine, is that sufficient, or should I get a pair of Teffilin later on that day that conforms to my Teffilin?

Examples:

- I wear Sefard Teffilin and one morning I use my friend's Teffilin who wears Ashkenaz, or vice versa.
- I wear Sefard/Ashkenaz and I borrow Sefradi Teffilin.
- I only have Rabbenu Taam Teffilin available in the morning.
- I use Ksav Arizal and I wear Beis Yosef or vice versa.

In each of these cases do I require a second Bracha and or a Second placment?

Comment: simchashatorah, I hope you don't mind that I cleaned up your question a little bit. If you find any faults with it, naturally feel free to make changes. I used your original transliteration scheme, and I hope that I managed to bring out the points of your question clearly without losing any of what you intended.

Comment: You should know there is a big argument as well about how to make parsha breaks between the different paragraphs. See SA OC 32:36 and MB there for three different opinions.

Comment: Thanx seth for cleaning it up I wish there would be some answers though

Answer (score 8):

Per [Harav Ben Tziyon Abba Shaul Zatzal](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19979&pgnum=54) and per [Rav Refael Hedya](http://www.bar-mitzva.com/question.asp) a Ashkenazi may put on Sefardi tefilin even L'Chatchila. A Sefardi may put on Chabad Tefilin since it follows the Shitas HaRambam. However a Sefardi should only put on Ashkenazi Tefilin when he has no choice and should not make a Bracha on them.

```
?האם מותר לאשכנזי להניח תפלין ספרדיות, ואם כן, האם זה בדיעבד? או אפילו לכתחילה
```

> בן אשכנז רשאי להניח תפלין שנכתבו כמנהג בני ספרד, ולברך עליהן, ואפילו
>   לכתחילה.
>
> תפלין שנכתבו כמנהג רבנו זלמן (כמנהג חב"ד) רשאים גם בני ספרד להניח
>   ולברך עליהן, כיוון שהן כמנהג הרמב"ם.
>
> בני ספרד לא יניחו תפלין שנכתבו כמנהג אשכנז, ואם אין לו תפלין אחרות חוץ
>   מתפלין כמנהג אשכנז -     הוא רשאי להניח אותן אך ללא ברכה

Comment: Who is Rav Refael Hedya? Is he a Sephardi?

Comment: HaRav Refael Hedya is the head of Yeshiva HaMekublim Bes Kail. http://beit-el.com/

Comment: Haha I was about to bring this Teshuva from the Or Letzion. Very interesting.

Comment: I'm guessing he is assuming all non-Chabad Ashkenazi tefillin are written with the Taz-setumah. I'm not so confident that is true.

Answer (score 1):

If one puts on only Rabbeinu Tam tefilin, one has NOT fulfilled the mitzvah of tefillin, according to any contemporary posek.

(see, among others, Chida 1, 1:4)

If the tefillin you borrow has straps that have been threaded to wrap around the arm differently than your custom (some go over the arm towards the body, some away from the body), you may need to run an extra loop above the elbow, in order to get the strap going in the correct direction for your minhag, once you make the bracha and start wrapping below the elbow.

As msh210 and alex pointed out - when borrowing another's tefilin, check to ensure that the knot which affixes the strap to the bais (tefillin box) is on the right of the box.

Comment: What is this reference to the Chida? One of his books?

Comment: ...where "in" and "out" are over the arm. (Under the arm, you go the other way.)

Comment: I'm not too sure about this idea of borrowing the opposite-handed tefillin. The straps will go the right way, true, but the yud-knot will be on the wrong side (away from the body rather than close to it). So which consideration outweighs which?

Comment: @msh210 right.  I originally was going to type "Ashekanzim who wear tefillin on their left arm wrap clockwise, whereas left-handers who wear tefillin on their right arm wrap counter-clockwise..." but it was all too wordy, so I went with 'in, out, away, towards'

Comment: @Alex, I was thinking the same thing. The knot's being on the right side is a _halacha_, isn't it? Whereas the direction of wrapping is a custom. I'd **guess** you should borrow the same-handed _t'filin_ and wrap it according to the lender's custom (but don't trust my guesses for practical matters!!).

Comment: @msh210, the Mechaber says (Orach Chaim 27:2) that this is the proper minhag, but it sounds like according to him at least it's not indispensable either. Though Mishnah Berurah (:7) cites Gra that it is a law from the Gemara, which I guess means that he considers it essential to fulfilling the mitzvah.

Comment: @alex we're talking about a (hopefully rare) instance when someone does not have his own tefillin, and needs to borrow a pair.  That's the textbook definition of "shas hadchak" (time of great need), and therefore one can rely on borrowing tefillin.  Same minhag, same hand, opposite minhag, opposite hand.

Comment: Of course. I (and @msh210) are just questioning whether, if a person has to borrow opposite-minhag tefillin, it's better (as you say) to borrow opposite-arm ones so that the straps turn in the wearer's usual direction, or same-arm ones so that the yud is on the correct side.

Comment: Okay - thank you msh210 and alex for catching that, and forcing a major rewrite.  Aha!  Open source tshuvos work!  :o)